# shows white page in chrome for MAC

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, cross-browser

We have web page with links which is open in new tab.Whenever we open the link page is loading in new tab but it shows white blank page hence html is loaded perfectly.
Now when we switch tab and again come to the tab then page content of the page displays properly.

I am facing this issue in MAC for chrome. firefox and safari browser working perfectly.

Comment: Uhm, and what kind of site are we talking about?

Comment: Any console messages, traces in body -> onload, link to code so we can see it? You say "shows white blank page hence html is loaded perfectly", but it sounds like the problem is that the html is not loading at all, or is loading in a way so strangely that it doesn't display.

Comment: @Roberrrt - Its Page with Static content and brightcove video.

Comment: @TimConsolazio - Yes Script and html loaded currently.Its specifically in Chrome for MAC

Comment: If you reveal that code to us, we could probably be of much more help. For instance, saying that it has a video player in it is interesting; how is that video player getting loaded, just via static HTML or are you inserting it with a script? (I did a lot of video work for Bloomberg.com and man those video scripts could be wonky).

Comment: Thanks @TimConsolazio - i have used brightcove video and i have also commented object tag and problem is still persist.